# How to shorten declaring named constants?

Tags: c++

So if I had to declare multiple constants of the same type like the example below, is there a way to increase efficiency while cutting down the length of the code? This is for C++.

```
const double DISCOUNT = .2;

const double CUT_OFF = 150;

const double SHIP_CHARGE = 8.5;

const double TAX_RATE = 0.0825;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223743/discussion-on-question-by-boopyboop-how-to-shorten-declaring-named-constants).

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can write it like the following, but really there's no reason to:

```
const double DISCOUNT = .2, CUT_OFF = 150, SHIP_CHARGE = 8.5, TAX_RATE = 0.0825;
```

It's debatable whether it's more readable or not. I personally don't recommend it, and the [C++ Core Guidelines don't recommend it either](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration).

As a side note, you should be using `constexpr` instead of `const` for things like this.

Comment: I did not include enough information in the initial question. What I've concluded was the best answer which does not prioritize a lower amount of characters over readability is your answer but after every comma you move the next constant down a line.

Comment: As I said in chat, in my opinion (no guarantee) you (BoopyBoop) can create your own answer with that compromise. It seems very applicable and has a noticable different look, though being functionally of course identical. Don't forget to explain your reasoning in prose.

Comment: Nikos, I trust that you won't begrudge me or BoopyBoop for missing out on the 15rep for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

```
#define A(b, c) const double b = c;
A(DISCOUNT, .2)
A(CUT_OFF, 150)
A(SHIP_CHARGE, 8.5)
A(TAX_RATE, .0825)
```

has fewer characters. But it's very hard to read indeed. From C++11 onwards prefer `constexpr` to `const`.

"Golfing" C++ code is never to be recommended. Write clear code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the way I would do it...

Instead ot T you my use something else.

```
using T = const double;

T DISCOUNT = .2;
T CUT_OFF = 150;
T SHIP_CHARGE = 8.5;
T TAX_RATE = 0.0825;
```

I also would use `constexpr` but in this case `const` is the same.